# How to work with virtual environment and make it default

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment named `knowhere` and I activate it in cmd using code `.\knowhere\Scripts\activate`. I have installed some libraries into this environment.
I have some python scripts stored on my pc. When I try to run them they are not working since they are not running in this virtual environment. Now how to make these scripts run.
Also is there any way to make "knowhere" as my default environment.

Comment: You are defeating the point of using virtual environments if you make it non-virtual. In your `knowhere` there should be a `bin` with a `python` executable. So instead of `python main.py` you do `/path/to/the/virtual/python main.py` to start the script.

Comment: This is not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @TinNguyen I dont want to make it non-virtual instead I want a way so the scripts run in that environment

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Virtual environments are only necessary when you want to work on two projects that use different versions of the same external dependency, e.g. Django 1.9 and Django 1.10 and so on. In such situations virtual environment can be really useful to maintain dependencies of both projects.

If you simply want your scripts to use Python libraries just install them on your system and you won't have that problem.

Comment: Or if you are working on code with other people and need an easy way to keep track of requirements. A global ```pip freeze > requirements.txt``` is wasteful.